# why does adding the where statement to this sql make it run so much slower?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have inherited a stored procedure and am having problems with it takes a very long time to run (around 3 minutes).  I have played around with it, and without the where clause it actually only takes 12 seconds to run.  None of the tables it references have a lot of data in them, can anybody see any reason why adding the main where clause below makes it take so much longer?

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[MissingReadingsReport] @SiteID    INT,
                                              @FormID    INT,
                                              @StartDate Varchar(8),
                                              @EndDate   Varchar(8)
As
  If @EndDate > GetDate()
    Set @EndDate = Convert(Varchar(8), GetDate(), 112)

  Select Dt.FormID,
         DT.FormDAte,
         DT.Frequency,
         Dt.DayOfWeek,
         DT.NumberOfRecords,
         Dt.FormName,
         dt.OrgDesc,
         Dt.CDesc
  FROM   (Select MeterForms.FormID,
                 MeterForms.FormName,
                 MeterForms.SiteID,
                 MeterForms.Frequency,
                 DateTable.FormDate,
                 tblOrganisation.OrgDesc,
                 CDesc = ( COMPANY.OrgDesc ),
                 DayOfWeek = CASE Frequency
                               WHEN 'Day' THEN DatePart(dw, DateTable.FormDate)
                               WHEN 'WEEK' THEN
                               DatePart(dw, MeterForms.FormDate)
                             END,
                 NumberOfRecords = CASE Frequency
                                     WHEN 'Day' THEN (Select TOP 1 RecordID
                                                      FROM   MeterReadings
                                                      Where
                                     MeterReadings.FormDate =
                                     DateTable.FormDate
                                     And MeterReadings.FormID =
                                         MeterForms.FormID
                                                      Order  By RecordID DESC)
                                     WHEN 'WEEK' THEN (Select TOP 1 ( FormDate )
                                                       FROM   MeterReadings
                                                       Where
                                     MeterReadings.FormDate >=
                                     DateAdd(d
                                     , -4,
                                     DateTable.FormDate)
                                     And MeterReadings.FormDate
                                         <=
                                         DateAdd(d, 3,
                                         DateTable.FormDate)
                                     AND MeterReadings.FormID =
                                         MeterForms.FormID)
                                   END
          FROM   MeterForms
                 INNER JOIN DateTable
                   ON MeterForms.FormDate <= DateTable.FormDate
                 INNER JOIN tblOrganisation
                   ON MeterForms.SiteID = tblOrganisation.pkOrgId
                 INNER JOIN tblOrganisation COMPANY
                   ON tblOrganisation.fkOrgID = COMPANY.pkOrgID
          /*this is what makes the query run slowly*/
          Where  DateTable.FormDAte >= @StartDAte
                 AND DateTable.FormDate <= @EndDate
                 AND MeterForms.SiteID = ISNULL(@SiteID, MeterForms.SiteID)
                 AND MeterForms.FormID = IsNull(@FormID, MeterForms.FormID)
                 AND MeterForms.FormID > 0)DT
  Where  ( Frequency = 'Day'
           And dt.NumberofRecords IS NULL )
          OR ( ( Frequency = 'Week'
                 AND DayOfWeek = DATEPART (dw, Dt.FormDate) )
               AND ( FormDate <> NumberOfRecords
                      OR dt.NumberofRecords IS NULL ) )
  Order  By FormID
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also please specify which RDBMS you're using. Looks like SqlServer.

Comment: What indexes are there on the tables? And especially are there indexes on the `DateTable.FormDAte`, `MeterForms.SiteID` and `MeterForms.FormID` fields?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you run EXPLAIN on the queries, both with and without the WHERE you suspect.

Comment: Post an explain plan. Without that no-one can give you an educated answer.

Comment: There is no explain plan in SQL Server, you need to look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your select with this:

```
FROM   
                (select siteid, formid, formdate from meterforms 
                 where siteid = isnull(@siteid, siteid) and
                        meterforms.formid = isnull(@formid, formid) and formid >0
                 ) MeterForms
                 INNER JOIN 
                 (select formdate from datetable where formdate >= @startdate and formdate <= @enddate) DateTable
                   ON MeterForms.FormDate <= DateTable.FormDate
                 INNER JOIN tblOrganisation
                   ON MeterForms.SiteID = tblOrganisation.pkOrgId
                 INNER JOIN tblOrganisation COMPANY
                   ON tblOrganisation.fkOrgID = COMPANY.pkOrgID
          /*this is what makes the query run slowly*/ 
          )DT
```

Comment: Thanks...in the end after a while looking at the query I narrowed it down to the 2 IsNull lines that were causing the issue, and from the data I have at the moment, these lines are not necessary anyway, so I have removed them, and now execution time is down from 3 minutes to 12 seconds.  I will also test out your SQL and see if that helps as an alternative fix...cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've already mentioned, it looks like the tables are properly indexed for columns in the join conditions but not for the columns in the where clause.

If you're not willing to change the query, it may be worth it to look into indexes defined on the where clause columns, specially that have the NULL check

Comment: +1 - You need indexes on those fields, especially when you have inequalities (>, <, etc) as these become range scans.

Answer (score 0):

I would be willing to bet that if you moved the Meterforms where clauses up to the from statement:

```
 FROM (select [columns] from MeterForms WHERE SiteID= ISNULL [etc] ) MF
      INNER JOIN [etc]
```

It would be faster, as the filtering would occur before the join. Also, having your INNER JOIN on your DateTable doing a <= down in your where clause may be returning more than you'd like ... try moving that between up to a subselect as well.

Have you run an execution plan on this yet to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: I have run an execution plan, I am not familiar with how to read them, but the part that stands out is : Cost 68% Index Spool (Eager Spool).

Comment: That usually indicates a lack of indexes... you have a lot going on in that where clause. If you're using SQL Management studio, hilight the query, go to tools, and "Database Engine Tuning Advisor"... see what it suggests for indices.

Comment: I have added indexes (non-unique, non clustered) to the fields in the where clause, but the query is only slightly faster (it has taken about 5 seconds off the 3 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Random suggestion, coming from an Oracle background:
What happens if you rewrite the following:

```
AND MeterForms.SiteID = ISNULL(@SiteID, MeterForms.SiteID)
AND MeterForms.FormID = IsNull(@FormID, MeterForms.FormID)
```

...to

```
AND (@SiteID is null or MeterForms.SiteID = @SiteID)
AND (@FormID is null or MeterForms.FormID = @FormID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...but it actually made the query run even slower :)